# Changing text canvas size

Tags: text, resize, after-effects

I realize I may not have my terminology down yet, I'm new to after effects, so I've attached a picture of what I am trying to achieve. I'd like to know how to resize the black canvas surrounding the "of magic" text layer can add more text.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Composition > Composition Settings` and change the size (in pixels) of that canvas under width and height.

Alternatively if this is a text block within an already larger canvas, click onto your text in the composition with the Type Tool `cmd+t`/`ctrl+t` and expand using the corner points to expand the visible type.